# VBScript/Classic ASP permission denied with fso.OpenTextFile after several uses

Tags: vbscript

I have a process that loops through a moderate amount of data (1MB) storing it in an array and then periodically writes it to the disk.  After several iterations, the script fails at fso.OpenTextFile() in my *else* section as though the file has not been closed or finished closing from the previous time the function was called.  The iteration # doesn't seem to be specific as it's happened anywhere between the 2nd and 10th iteration that I can tell.  The file is actually created and being appended to so it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.  I considering adding a time delay to the process but don't want to necessarily add overhead to an already long process.

OS:  Windows 2012 R2

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated.

```
'Write array to disk
sub writeFile()
        'on error resumenext
        set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        if needToCreateFile then
            set objTextFile = fso.CreateTextFile(server.mappath("google/linklist.html"),true)
            objTextFile.writeLine("<!DOCTYPE html>")
            objTextFile.writeLine("<html>")
            objTextFile.writeLine("<title>")
            objTextFile.writeLine("Content Listing")
            objTextFile.writeLine("</title>")
            needToCreateFile = false
        else 
            ' OpenTextFile Method needs a Const value
            ' ForAppending = 8 ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
            Set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile (filename, ForAppending, True)
        end if

        'Write contents of array to file
        for each link in linkList
            if link <>"" and not isNull(link) then
                objTextFile.writeLine(link & "<br>")
            end if
        next
        objTextFile.writeLine("</html>")
        objTextFile.Close
        set fso = nothing
        set objTextFile = nothing
        'on  error goto 0

end sub
```

**Follow Up - Solved**

Adding a 3 second delay solved the problem, but significantly delayed the processing time.  So, rather than opening and closing the file each time I wanted to write to it, I simply left it open until the entire script was done and thus I didn't need the delay.

```
sub writeFile()

        if needToCreateFile then
            set objTextFile = fs.CreateTextFile(server.mappath("google/linklist.html"),true)
            objTextFile.writeLine("<!DOCTYPE html>")
            objTextFile.writeLine("<html>")
            objTextFile.writeLine("<title>")
            objTextFile.writeLine("Content Listing")
            objTextFile.writeLine("</title>")
            needToCreateFile = false
        end if

        'Write contents of array to file
        for each link in linkList
            if link <>"" and not isNull(link) then
                objTextFile.writeLine(link & "<br>")
            end if
        next
        objTextFile.writeLine("</html>")
       ' objTextFile.Close
       ' set fso = nothing
       ' set objTextFile = nothing
end sub
```

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem yourself, please post it as an answer of your own and accept it, so that it's removed from the unanswered questions queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a 3 second delay solved the problem, but significantly delayed the processing time. So, rather than opening and closing the file each time I wanted to write to it, I simply left it open until the entire script was done and thus I didn't need the delay.  See modified script above.